# Maya 3d view port issues

Tags: 3d, models, maya

Hi currently i am working on modelling an object within view port, but i have issues here. On my right panel view port, when i try to alter an vertex of an cube i'm getting an 3d effect similar like this:

[image]

But instead i should see effect similar like this:

[image]

Where am i wrong here? Thanks

Comment: You're supposed to select all vertices that are on top of each other from that view, just select them by dragging a selection box around the vertex you want to move.

Comment: Hi i am just select only 1 vertex point..but i have this kind issues.

Comment: I'm telling you to make a selection box around that one vertex. To get not just the frontmost vertex but also select all the vertices behind it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you only selected and moved one vertex, when in fact you need all the vertices in that row. That is, all the vertices stacked onto one spot in an orthogonal view.

If you selected it with selection box and it selected 1 vertex, you may have turn on/off backface culling or your selection tool based on camera selection.
Double click on selection tool to view tool setting and uncheck camera based selection.
it could work.